# "impede" vs. "impede on"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I can’t figure out whether the following sentence needs the word *on* or not:

> 1. It was getting crowded, impeding our ability to move around.
> 2. It was getting crowded, impeding **on** our ability to move around.

For some reason, both sound just a little bit wrong to me.

Comment: Given the type of question you’ve asked, I think you might be interested in [our sister site for English Learners](http://ell.stackexhange.com).  ELL tends to be a better fit for these sorts of questions than ELU does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Impede* simply means *hinder* or possibly *prevent* or *delay*:

> **impede** *verb* [with object]
>   delay or prevent (someone or something) by obstructing them; hinder:
>   *the sap causes swelling which can impede breathing*
>
> [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/impede?q=impede)

It doesn't take a preposition.

*Impinge* **does** take a preposition; something *impinges on* something else if it has an effect on it:

> **impinge** *verb (impinges, impinging, impinged)*  [no object]
>       have an effect, especially a negative one:
>   *several factors impinge on market efficiency*
>   • advance over an area belonging to someone or something else; encroach:
>     *the proposed fencing would impinge on a public bridleway*
>   •    (impinge on/upon) *Physics* strike:
>     *the gases impinge on the surface of the liquid*
>
> [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/impinge?q=impinge)